# Bulk copy to multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datagrid

my application is currently reading data from a csv file into my GUI and then displaying , at the moment the code looks like this :

```
try
        {
            //Browse for file
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            //Only show .csv files
            ofd.Filter = "Microsoft Office Excel Comma Separated Values File|*.csv";
            DialogResult result = ofd.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=ionCalc;Integrated Security=True");
                string filepath = ofd.FileName;
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath);
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                string[] value = line.Split(',');
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataRow row;

                foreach (string dc in value)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc));
                }

                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    value = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    if (value.Length == dt.Columns.Count)
                    {
                        row = dt.NewRow();
                        row.ItemArray = value;
                        dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                }
                SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock);
                bc.DestinationTableName = "Inventory";
                bc.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("IN", "IN");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Fund", "Fund");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Status", "Status");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("ShareCurrency", "ShareCurrency");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("PriceFrequency", "PriceFrequency");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("ClassCode", "ClassCode");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Simulation", "Simulation");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Hedged", "Hedged");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("FundCurrency", "FundCurrency");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Type", "Type");
                con.Open();
                bc.WriteToServer(dt);
                bc.Close();
                connection.Close();
```

Which correctly throws all the data into the datagrid for the inventory. However I want to make sure that while the data is getting placed in the inventory table that the name and fund have their distinct names passed to their respective tables ...any ideas ?

Apologies for the starting line , for some reason keeps being cut out

Comment: So, you want to insert the name and fund DISTINCT values into other tables? I assume for lookup? You could isolate the distinct values of Name and Fund and use another 2 bulk copy statements...Or run a script after the insert that does this for you? Using SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: @DanielDawes the bulk copy seems like the best method , is it just a case of copy and pasting the current one an removing the unwanted columns ?

Comment: If you want the DISTINCT funds and names, then I would use a nice LINQ statement against that data table you have there to pull them out and into new data tables, then write 2 more bulk copy statements based on those new data tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
var names = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(o=>o.Field<string>("Name").Distinct());
var funds = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(o=>o.Field<string>("Fund").Distinct());
```

Once you have these 2 collections you can convert them to datatables as you see fit (Lots of suggestions about the site), then use more SqlBulkCopy to process them